# nuspec dependency allowedVersions?

Tags: nuget, nuspec

I have a nuspec file that builds a nuget-package. I would like to control the dependencies, where I allow a range of versions, but what to always install a spesific version.

Basically this (not valid syntax):
`<dependency id="Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies" version="8.2.0.2" allowedVersions="6.0.0" />`

I want the nuget to dependency to accept 6 or higer (up to 9), but always want it to install 8.2.0.2 as default.

If I had version="6.0.0", it would always install the 6 version?

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to specify an accepted version range in a nuspec-file with a [version-range syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/package-versioning#version-ranges-and-wildcards). Accepting every version with a major version between 6 and (including) 9 would be specified by `[6.0.0, 10.0.0)`.

What I understand from your question is that you want to specify an accepted version range but you want to force a certain version to be installed. There is no way I know of to achieve this but I also don't see the requirement for it: By specifying an accepted version range, the nuspec-file specifies to which versions of the dependency packages this package is compatible with. Hence, all accepted versions should work.

Forcing a certain version to be installed contradicts this compatibility statement in my opinion. This sounds as if you want to achieve a different goal: To verify that a consistent version of a NuGet package is installed in an application. This, however, should be solved on the consuming side, i.e. the solution that installs the NuGet packages. Assume the nuspec-file defines a package A that accepts all versions `[6.0.0, 10.0.0)` from `Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies`, but the consuming solution should always use version `8.2.0.2`. Then this version `8.2.0.2` should be installed there first and afterwards the current version of package A can be installed, finding its dependency to `Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies` already resolved.

To achieve a consistent consuming solution, we implement checks on the CI server that verify that every package is referenced in all projects in exactly one version. By this we get a consistent product while keeping the actual NuGet packages flexible to be used with a different version of dependency packages in other products.

Comment: You are exactly right. I was so focused on the install process of the nuget file, that I neglected to consider that the dependency can/is being controlled on the consuming side. This insight fixes my issue, thank you